# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasPermission') discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have coded a discord bot but i have a problem, when i execute my command it shows me a error.

- Error:

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
                                

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasPermission')
```

- Code where the error comes up:

```
    if (command === "add") {
                if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
                    return message.reply("Desoler, vous ne pouvez pas effectuer cette commande car vous n'ette pas administrateur");
                var fs = require("fs");
                let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
                let args = messageArray.slice(1);
                var account = args[0]
                var service = args[1]
                const filePath = __dirname + "/" + args[1] + ".txt";
                fs.appendFile(filePath, os.EOL + args[0], function (err) {
                    if (err) return console.log(err);
                    message.channel.send("Terminer !")
                });
```

I already tried to replace `hasPermission` with `permissions.has` but it still does not work.

Comment: It means `message.member` is `null`. Where do you send the message? In a DM or a text channel?

Comment: In the text channel

Comment: Do you have the `GUILD_MEMBERS` and `GUILD_MESSAGES` intents enabled?

Comment: No i dont have intents enabled

Answer (score -1):

Define your client like that

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: 32767 });
```

Also make sure intents are enabled in the developer portal and use `GuildMember#permissions.has`

Comment: Oh i have activated the presence intent and server intent and it work thanks you very much !